# ie 7-8 does not support object tag?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, internet-explorer-7

I created my website's header and footer in a separate html file and I am embedding those files in my web pages.

After all the hard work and completing the website I came across an error in IE8. My header and footer are aligned all over the place in IE7 & 8.

```
<footer>
    <div id="divObjFooter">
        <object data="/footer.html" type="text/html">
            &nbsp;
        </object>
    </div>
</footer>
```

**Update - fixed for any version running html5**
Finally found a way to support ie any version.

```
<!--[if IE]>
            <div id="footer">
                <div id="divObjFooter">
                    <iframe src="footer.html">&nbsp;</iframe>
                </div>
            </div>
        <![endif]-->

        <![if !IE]>     
            <footer>
                <div id="divObjFooter">
                    <object data="footer.html" type="text/html">&nbsp;</object>
                </div>
            </footer>
        <![endif]>
```

Comment: Have you tried using iframe instead of object?

Comment: Your HTML isn't even valid. Why would this work?

Comment: @JohnFx any reasons html is not valid ? all my web pages are html5 validated

Comment: @Adam i did tried but in html5 most of its properties is not supported

Comment: i found out that most of html5 is not supported by ie 8 ..i think this  is it. i have used header and foooter element and ie 8 doesnot know anything about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!--[if IE]>
        <div id="footer">
            <div id="divObjFooter">
                <iframe src="footer.html">&nbsp;</iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
    <![endif]-->

    <![if !IE]>     
        <footer>
            <div id="divObjFooter">
                <object data="footer.html" type="text/html">&nbsp;</object>
            </div>
        </footer>
    <![endif]>
```

Answer (score 1):

ie8 and earlier do not support HTML5 tags (in your case, the `<footer>` tag), and therefore do not style them. To get around this, you could simply use `div`'s with id's and style them from there, or, if you want to use the latest and greatest HTML5 stuff, you can use an html5 shiv.

I would recommend the script hosted on Google code:
https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/

Answer (score 0):

Check the website [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/) for browser support of `HTML5` and `CSS3` before you use new tags and selectors against your target audience.

IE<10 supports very little (less then 40%) modern html and css. You will likely have to use modernizr or something similar or simply not use the latest "shiny"

Answer (score 0):

To answer first the question in the title: IE has supported the `object` element since IE 4 (though early implementations were lousy). Your problem does not seem to be with that element but with your styling of the `footer` element – a completely different issue.

The `footer` element is not supported by IE 7 and IE 8. This matters little as such, since the default effect would be just making the element content a block, and your content is already a block (a `div` element). What causes the trouble is that you have some CSS rules that set properties on the `footer` element. This won’t work on IE 7–8, since they do not recognize the element even in the sense of letting you style it.

There is a quick fix: put the following before your first style sheet or reference to any style sheet:

```
<script>document.createElement('footer')</script>
```

This is effectively what many “shims” or “polyfills” or whatever you call them are doing, and if you have an issue with `footer` only, you might use just the quick fix.

Alternatively, set your CSS rules on the `div` inside, using the `#divObjFooter` selector.

P.S. Using `object` (or `iframe`) to include a footer is possible, but clumsy. It will include an HTML file in a subwindow of the document window, and links won’t work normally etc. If at all possible, it is better to use server side tools, like Server-Side Includes (SSI) or their more advanced counterparts, or page management software.